# Run python script as if it were located somewhere else

Tags: python, import, module, path

Is it possible to run a python script from one location but have the script execute as if it were located somewhere else (so imports etc all work as expected).

My scenario is this:

- Application is located under /opt/foo/bin, application main entry point is `foo.py`
- Under `/opt/foo` there are a bunch of packages/modules which `foo.py` then imports
- We run application as `cd /opt/foo/bin && python foo.py`

I'd like to be able to copy *just* `foo.py` to `/tmp` and run it with `cd /tmp && python foo.py`. I'd like it to execute as if it were the `foo.py` living under `/opt/foo/bin`. I can modify the `foo.py` under `/tmp` if required.

Hopefully this makes sense to someone. Modifying the `foo.py` under `/opt/foo/bin` is not an option. One possibility might be creating a folder under `/tmp` i.e. `/tmp/foo` and symlinking everything except `foo.py` - but I'm hoping there's an easier way to accomplish what I want!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's [a description of how Python searches for modules when you import them](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). One solution to your problem is to add the directory /opt/foo/bin to your PYTHONPATH. You could also modify your path within foo.py in order to find the module, e.g.

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append('/opt/foo/bin')
 import foo
```

Comment: This solution works for simple cases, but wasn't working for our application because our application was doing it's own fiddling with sys.path, based on the location of the script.

Comment: Was there any solution found for coping with such issue?